# What is an alternative to updating an image in firebase storage bucket than deleting and uploaded?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm storing blog posts in a firebase database. Blog post can have an image. I have a storage bucket where I store the images, and I save the url to the image with the post in the database. Now I'm working on editing posts. Part of this involves uploading a different image. I don't want the images to pile up indefinitely in my storage bucket. I'd prefer to replace the old image with the new one. This is how I'm doing it:

```
                const bucket = fbAdmin.storage().bucket('***');
                if (fields.filename) {
                    await bucket.file(fields.filename).delete();
                }
                const result = await bucket.upload(files.image.path, {metadata: {contentType: files.image.type}});
```

In other words, I delete the old file then upload the new one.

But I've got to think there must be a simpler way of doing this. Rather than delete and upload, isn't there an update function? Something like:

```
bucket.update(files.image.path, {name: oldFileName});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just write to the same path in the bucket without first deleting the file.

```
const bucket = fbAdmin.storage().bucket('***');
const result = await bucket.upload(files.image.path, {metadata: {contentType: files.image.type}});
```

If the file already exists, this will overwrite it.

Comment: That's not the path where to write the file. That's the path where to get the file on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

While Frank's solution does technically work, if you have any metadata associated with your object, his approach removes it.

I found that I was able to maintain the metadata by using a similar approach.  This also preserves custom metadata.

```js
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('***');
const destObjPath = 'some-path.jpg';
const fileRef = bucket.file(destObjPath);

// Get the object's existing metadata
const existingMetadata = (await fileRef.getMetadata())[0];

// Delete checksum and other calculated metadata fields
delete existingMetadata.crc32c;
delete existingMetadata.etag;
delete existingMetadata.md5Hash;
delete existingMetadata.size;
delete existingMetadata.timeCreated;
delete existingMetadata.timeStorageClassUpdated;
delete existingMetadata.updated;

// Provide the copied metadata along with the object update
await bucket.upload(files.image.path, {
    destination: destObjPath,
    metadata: existingMetadata
});
```